# "405 Method not allowed" in Laravel 5.6.14

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am just learning laravel resource methods to build a basic API. Below is the code of my **api.php** file that shows all the API routes.

```
// List Articles
Route::get('articles', 'ArticleController@index');

// List Single Article
Route::get('article/{id}', 'ArticleController@show');

// Create New Article
Route::post('article', 'ArticleController@store');

// Update Article
Route::put('article', 'ArticleController@store');

// Delete Article
Route::delete('article/{id}', 'ArticleController@destroy');
```

This works perfectly on **get** and **delete** methods. But for Post method, it is throwing error "405 Method not allowed". I am using Postman to test the API calls.

To be specific, below is the exact error Postman shows

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Also attaching screenshot of Postman
[image]

Comment: Change any method name of route. For example, change function name for post method from store to `storeArticle`! like: `Route::post('article', 'ArticleController@storeArticle');`

Comment: I tried that already by changing "store" to "save". Also now tried "storeArticle" as you instructed, but that also doesn't work. Infact, if I delete the method from controller, it still shows same error

Comment: @aslamdoctor:  Give you error because may be Put and Post method name are same

Comment: @aslamdoctor: Please change your method name store to storeArticle and change url name article to store-article and try

Comment: Try replacing `post` and `put` with `Route::match(['post', 'put'], 'article', 'ArticleController@store');`. Although I have to add that for `put` routes it is common practice to directly address the updated entity, meaning you should split both routes into separate controller methods and ask for an `{id}` in the `put` method like you did for the single get route.

Comment: @aslamdoctor: Try this now: `Route::post('save-article', 'ArticleController@saveArticle');`

Comment: @AddWeb.. its not a form. I just built API endpoints and testing them on Postman. As you see my other comments, if I delete the route line code, it still shows same error.

Comment: @HirenGohel tried that too. No change.

Comment: @aslamdoctor: Are you sure you are using POST method in postman when calling post method?

Comment: @HirenGohel yes, check the question. I updated it with screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167855/discussion-between-aslamdoctor-and-hiren-gohel).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change you store route like this:

```
Route::post('article/store', 'ArticleController@store');
```

Because you send post request from Postman to

> /article/store

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` indicates the POST route can not be found for the requested url, but other methods are available.

This can be because you did not define it (correctly), or it has a conflict with another route in your config.

You can check the current routes with `php artisan route:list`

If you want to use resource controllers, instead of defining all the resource routes and actions yourself, why are you not using the `Route::resource()` method?

```
Route::resource('article', ArticleController::class);
```

This will generate all resource routes for you:

```
Verb        Path                    Action  Route Name
GET         /article                index   article.index
GET         /article/create         create  article.create
POST        /article                store   article.store
GET         /article/{article}      show    article.show
GET         /article/{article}/edit edit    article.edit
PUT/PATCH   /article/{article}      update  article.update
DELETE      /article/{article}      destroy article.destroy
```

The action translates to the action name in your controller, so for example, a request to `POST /article` will call the controller action: `ArticleController@store`.

In your case, I see that you are not using create or edit views, so instead of using the `Route::resource()` method, you can use the `Route::apiResource()` method, which will exclude routes that present HTML views for creating and editing your articles.

```
Route::apiResource('article', Api\ArticleController::class);
```

This will create your routes like:

```
Verb        Path                    Action  Route Name
GET         /article                index   article.index
POST        /article                store   article.store
GET         /article/{article}      show    article.show
PUT/PATCH   /article/{article}      update  article.update
DELETE      /article/{article}      destroy article.destroy
```

You can also auto-generate the resource controller to match your resource routes, this will generate the controller file for you.

```
php artisan make:controller Api/ArticleController --api
```

This will generate that file in `Http/Controllers/Api/ArticleController` with a mock of all the actions defined by the route which you can then use.

[More info on resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers)

PS.

Your PUT route does not take an id and it calls store, it is good practice to split the actions for POST (creating new) and PUT/PATCH (full/partial update of existing objects) in your controller.

Reason for this is that by convention, POST will create a new entity and doing a post again will (most likely) create another, so every request will have a different result.

PUT requests, on the other hand, are idempotent, meaning you should be able to do a PUT request multiple times on the same object and the output should be the same for all these requests. PATCH is a bit of a weird one here, it can be idempotent, but is not required. But when using Laravel, PATCH requests are usually handled by the same controller action which handles the PUT requests, and (depending on implementation) will be idempotent.

PSS.

I would not recommend using `POST /article/store` and follow the REST convention of doing a POST on the resource name itself instead. `POST /article`

Answer (score 4):

If sll is active on your domain, you should request like HTTPS://yourdomain.com . You should check that, then try again.

Comment: thank you for this good reminder, I had already had this error

Answer (score 3):

The `methodNotAllowed` exception indicates that a route doesn't exist for the HTTP method you are requesting.

Your form is set up to make a `POST` request, so your route needs to use `Route::post()` to receive this.

Be sure that request on **postman** is set on `POST`

Remember to clear route cache after any route change:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

**Try also changing settings on postman: Do not send anything in headers - I mean delete Content-Type**

Comment: Tried clearing route cache. Still same issue. Check the screenshot too in question, I updated it.

Comment: Try also changing settings on postman: Do not send anything in headers - I mean delete Content-Type